# How to enable autoimport in GoClipse?

Tags: eclipse, go, import, goclipse

According to [this post](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/issues/66) autoimport could be enabled in GoClipse:

> ```
> 1) install goimports:
> go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/goimports
>
> 2) in eclipse goto: Preferences -> Go -> Go Formatter and set it to be the path of the goimports bin
>
> This will fix all imports when you format. If you combine this with #67, then imports will be automatically fixed on save.
> ```

**Problem**

When I try to search for Go Formatter in Eclipse I cannot find it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe, it is gofmt. Try to change the gofmt path to goimports path.

Comment: I have run the get command to get the import code, but I cannot find the  binary. I was expecting that this works the same as for gocode. After running the get command the gocode binary resides in the bin directory of the eclipse workspace, but this works differently for goimports?

Comment: Hi @Alfred. Wondering if you got it resolved. If not, did my answer help you? Thanks.

Comment: @bshuster13 Now it works. Thank you. Perhaps you could add the ctrl shift f to your answer.

Comment: @Alfred well done! thanks for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that my eyes caught out:

I know that goimports URL is no longer google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/goimports.

So lets try the following:

1. Execute `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports`
2. Go to `Preferences` -> `Go`
3. Set `gofmt` to `${GOPATH}/bin/goimports` (which is where goimports is located)
4. Restart `Eclipse` and make sure it uses `goimports` when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: When I save the file, nothing happens. For example, `regex` should be imported but nothing happens

Comment: @Alfred: you need to "format" the code. "right mouse click"->source->Go format(gofmt) or `ctr-shift-f`.

Comment: @RickyA Thank you. I was assuming that it was ctrl shift o to organize imports like in java.