# Should developers replace Eclipse by another IDE if they start coding Go as GoClipse lacks major features?

Tags: eclipse, import, autocomplete, goclipse

There was a language switch in the team recently. The team used Eclipse as an IDE for a couple of years. The first thing that was done was [installing the GoClipse plugin in Eclipse](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/master/documentation/Installation.md), but after a couple of hours some of the developers decided to quit Eclipse. One of them said:

> GoClipse lacks major features, like autocomplete, navigating to
>   functions and autoimport.

**Aim:** to provide a complete guide how to configure these features so that developers will continue to use GoClipse instead of replacing it by another IDE

**Problems**

*Problem 1*

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> results in:

[image]

---

*Problem 2*

Autocomplete, e.g. typing `fmt.` results in:

[image]

---

*Problem 3*

[Autoimports do not work in GoClipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976532/how-to-enable-autoimport-in-goclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

There is no reason why GoClipse should be replaced by developers as the major features work in GoClipse as well

**Answers**

*Answer 1*

[image]

To enable navigating, i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>, follow the instructions, i.e. issue `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle` and subsequently click <kbd>Browse</kbd> and select the path where the `oracle` binary resides. Note: if `export GOPATH=/path/to/workspace` then the binary resides in the bin directory of the project.

---

*Answer 2*

To enable autocomplete issue `go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode`, click <kbd>Browse</kbd> and select the gocode binary (See answer 1)

---

[*Answer 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976532/how-to-enable-autoimport-in-goclipse/33988967#33988967)

To enable autoimport issue `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` and add the path to goimports to the gofmt field.

Answer (score 0):

Step number 7 of the [Installation guide](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/master/documentation/Installation.md) reads:

> "For initial setup, follow the instructions at the configuration
>   section in the User Guide."

And indeed the [configuration section](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/UserGuide.md#configuration) explains what other external programs you need (such as gocode and oracle), and how to configure them.